# Supersearch for categories and keywords

Tags: solspace, supersearch

I can't seem to get the behaviour I want out of a search result using Solspace Supersearch.

Here's the scenario:

I want a keyword search on some specific fields and on category names. I have 2 channel fields (in the same channel, all set to searchable) that look like this:

```
street_name (example: "Boylston")
map_address (example: "100 Boylston Street, Boston, MA")
```

and category names that look like this:

```
"Downtown" ... "Jamaica Plains" ... "West End" etc...
```

my Solspace result tag and URL look like this:

```
url: search&keywords=West+End

{exp:super_search:results
        paginate="bottom"
        limit="10"
        inclusive_keywords="no" 
        keyword_search_category_name="yes"
        search_in="map_address|street_name" 
        relevance="street_name=5"
        }
Output results here...
{/exp:super_search:results}
```

Now searching for street names/addresses seems to work fine. And searching for categories actually works fine too, **unless** the category name is in two segments. For example, when searching for "West End", I get no results, but if I search for "West", I'll get some mixed results but they will include entries (there are only two in my channel) with the category "West End" (both of which do not have the term "West" or "End" in any of their fields, so the category_name search must have worked). Same result when searching for "End", mixed results but those two do show up.

I have the same issue with all of my two segment category names, ex: "Jamaica Plains" gets no results, but "Jamaica" or "Plains" does.

I tried using a combination of the category-like and keywords search, but category-like is too fuzzy ("North End" results are very mixed with "South End", "West End", "South Boston", etc...). It almost works if I force category-like and keywords to search the same terms, but then they only include results that have A) The first word of the search term is found in the category name B) any part of the search term is found street_name or map_address.

When turning on debug, any time I use this parameter in my result tag

```
keyword_search_category_name="yes"
```

and my keyword search is more than one segment ("Jamaica+Plains") I get this PHP error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: super_search/mod.super_search.php

Line Number: 8408
```

We're using EE 2.9.0 and Supersearch 2.2.1. I've poured through the docs trying to find a way to search for colloquial location names as categories ("North End",etc) and addresses as just text fields. It might be a bug, but I'd take any suggestions on how to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of this writing, this is a known issue (both the PHP error and the keyword_search_category_name="" parameter not working as expected). We have noted the issue, but we do not have an ETA for a fix.

By the way, the latest info about add-on releases are announced on Twitter and are available in the add-on's changelog.